# Webcam light turns on, when I use media applications like Banshee and Rhythmbox

Tags: power-management, banshee, webcam

I have an Asus laptop. It is the X53 Model. I use Ubuntu 11.04 on it and I have no problems but when I try to open a multimedia program the LED of my webcam turns on. What can I do to about it?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 2):

These programs are activating the webcam in order to get some information and do a light hardware scan. There isn't much you could do about it, but you could ask them in a bug report to provide an option to stop hardware checking every time they load.